# Por que source de input filter regresa mas de un solo character con letras, pero no con caracteres espciales (ej: emojis)

Tags: android, kotlin

Uno de los problemas que estoy intentando de resolver en que cuando ingreso emojis mediante un edit text quiero que cuenten como 1 solo emoji y no con su valor de 2, 4, etc. Ya que cuando ingreso de esa manera el limite del edit text es consumido por los valores de los emojis.

El código presentado puede hacer actualmente que los emojis cuenten como 1, el problema es que cuando ingreso letras, el `source` del `filter` me regresa mas de un caracter. Ejemplo: ingreso "rrr" y regresa esa cantidad, entonces cuando quiero agregar mas no me deja y se elimina el caracter anterior debido a que el `sourceLength` es mayor cuando todavia hay limite disponible (5 de limite como ejemplo). Espero y puedan guiarme un poco de por que causa ese comportamiento.

```
class UnicodeInputFilter(private val maxLength: Int) : InputFilter {

    override fun filter(
        source: CharSequence?,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        dest: Spanned?,
        dstart: Int,
        dend: Int
    ): CharSequence? {
        val destLength = getCharacters(dest)
        val sourceLength = getCharacters(source)
        val keep = maxLength - destLength

        return when {
            keep <= 0 -> {
                "" // Reject input if it exceeds the maximum length
            }
            keep >= sourceLength -> {
                null // Accept the entire input if it fits within the maximum length
            }
            else -> {
                source?.subSequence(start, keep)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getCharacters(charSequence: CharSequence?): Int {
        val charIterator = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance().apply {
            setText(charSequence.toString())
        }

        var result = 0
        while (charIterator.next() != BreakIterator.DONE) {
            result += 1
        }
        return result
    }
}
```